# SQL: Undo YTD cum sum with LAG then re-aggregate with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

**Background**

I'm working with monthly employee-level fiscal-year-to-date (FYTD) vacation hours taken for 20k employees going back 6 years. There are at least 20 million records in the table.

*Note* Our fiscal year begins September 1.

**Example Table**

```
| Month  | Country | Employee | Vacation_Hours_YTD |
|--------|---------|----------|--------------------|
| 201707 | USA     | A        | 92                 |
| 201708 | USA     | A        | 100                |
| 201709 | USA     | A        | 6                  |
| 201710 | USA     | A        | 15                 |
| 201707 | USA     | B        | 60                 |
| 201708 | USA     | B        | 60                 |
| 201709 | USA     | B        | 10                 |
| 201710 | USA     | B        | 12                 |
| 201707 | CA      | X        | 82                 |
| 201708 | CA      | X        | 94                 |
| 201709 | CA      | X        | 7                  |
| 201710 | CA      | X        | 20                 |
| 201707 | CA      | Y        | 45                 |
| 201708 | CA      | Y        | 80                 |
| 201709 | CA      | Y        | 0                  |
| 201710 | CA      | Y        | 12                 |
```

**Desired Output**

```
| Month  | Country | Total_Vacation_Hours |
|--------|---------|----------------------|
| 201708 | USA     | 8                    |
| 201709 | USA     | 16                   |
| 201710 | USA     | 11                   |
| 201708 | CA      | 43                   |
| 201709 | CA      | 7                    |
| 201710 | CA      | 25                   |
```

I need to:

1. Undo the Fiscal YTD calculation to get the monthly amount, and
2. Group by country to hours per country per month.

**My attempt**

I've done `LAG()` `GROUP BY` and a `CASE WHEN` separately. But I'm having trouble combining them all. I also don't know how to parse the fiscal year from the Month column.

```
SELECT
   [Month]
   ,[Country]
   ,SUM([Vacation_Hours_YTD]) - coalesce(lag(SUM([Vacation_Hours_YTD])) over (partition by [Country] order by [Month]), 0) as 'Total_Vacation_Hours'
  FROM Vacation_YTD_Table
GROUP BY    [Month],[Country]
```

Comment: how do you get from 92 to 1800 for `201707 USA` ?

Comment: @Squirrel sorry I wasn't clear. the example table is just 8 rows. i.e. there are 5k employees in the USA alone.

Comment: can you edit the desired output at least it correspond to the sample that you have posted.

Comment: done. can you at least have a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query almost got it, the point is for month of Sept, you don't subtract from previous cumulative figure

```
; with
cte as
(
    select  Month, Country, Employee, 
            Vacation_Hours  = Vacation_Hours_YTD 
                            - CASE  WHEN Month % 100 = 9 -- Sept
                                    THEN 0
                                    ELSE LAG(Vacation_Hours_YTD) 
                                         OVER (PARTITION BY Country, Employee 
                                                   ORDER BY Month)
                                    END
    from    Vacation_YTD_Table
)
select  Month, Country, SUM(Vacation_Hours) as Total_Vacation_Hours 
from    cte 
where   Vacation_Hours  is not null  -- this is to exclude 201707
group by Month, Country
order by Month
```